# How can the opacity of a program be controled through a settings window in real time?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, settings, opacity

I am trying to change the `Opacity` of the main application window through a settings window popup in **real time**. What is the proper way of doing this?

So far, I have tried using a `Slider` to output the value to the settings file. When the settings popup is closed, the main window refreshes its opacity property based on the settings file. This method works but I'd like the ability to change the opacity and view the result in real time.

The second method I tried was using a `Style` and applying it to the MainWindow. Then on slider move, the style would be overridden with the value from the slider. This works in real time. But for whatever reason, the *settings popup window opacity is also affected even though no style is applied to it*.

Here is a sample project named `OpacityTest` with a main window, a button to open settings popup and slider to control the program's opacity.

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="OpacityTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="wrapper">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="false"/>
            <Setter x:Name="opacitySetter" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="OpacityTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Style="{DynamicResource wrapper}" Background="#FFCDCDCD" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="Settings" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

New window labeled Settings, Settings.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="OpacityTest.Settings"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Settings" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Slider x:Name="ChangeTransparency" MinWidth="138" MinHeight="22" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Value="1" Minimum=".05" Maximum="1" LargeChange=".01" SmallChange=".01" TickFrequency="100" IsSnapToTickEnabled="False" MouseMove="ChangeTransparency_MouseMove"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace OpacityTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Settings settings = new Settings();
            settings.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Settings.xaml.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    namespace OpacityTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for Settings.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class Settings : Window
        {
            public Settings()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void ChangeTransparency_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                Style style = new Style { TargetType = typeof(Window) };
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(OpacityProperty, Opacity = ChangeTransparency.Value));
                Application.Current.Resources["wrapper"] = style;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit obvious.  Don't change the style, that affects all windows that use that style.  Change the window's Opacity instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `Style` is behaving as if it were declared in a XAML file in a way that affects *all* `Window`s, not just the `wrapper` style, e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="Window"> ... </Style>
```

Instead of:

```
<Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="wrapper"> ... </Style>
```

I'm not immediately sure of how to declare it the way you're trying to, but a much easier way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to put this in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    this.SetBinding(OpacityProperty,
                  new Binding("Value") { Source = settings.ChangeTransparency });
    settings.ShowDialog();
}
```

No handler on `ChangeTransparency` is required this way. The only reason I might consider modifying the `Style` instead is if you can have multiple `MainWindow`s at once, and want one `Settings` window (opened from any of them) to control them all at once.

As an aside, if you do find that you need to attach to `ChangeTransparency`, you should attach a handler to its [`ValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.valuechanged.aspx) event instead of `MouseMove` (while `MouseMove` will generally work out, it's really not the same; e.g. for keyboard input, only `ValueChanged` will fire).

If `Settings` can be used from other windows and/or has more properties, you might wish to change `Settings` to take a `Window` (or other type) in its constructor, and set up the binding(s) there instead, to keep your code/logic centralized and clean.

Comment: I also agree with using `ValueChanged`for the event. The reason I went with `MouseMove`is because the value of the slider loads from a settings file as soon as the settings window is open. This throws a 'System.NullReferenceException' error because I have a label attached to the value to show the percentage. Since the label is null at the time the value changed due to loading from settings, there is an error.

Comment: @MiddleCSharp Ah, I see. Better (IMHO) ways of handling that would be to either put a null check in your handler (e.g. `if (myLabel != null) ...`) or a `bool` to indicate when you're loading, to prevent handlers from erroring or doing weird things, like saving the default value of 1 over your settings (e.g. at the start of your constructor, set a `bool isLoading` field to true; at the end of it, set it to false; in your `ValueChanged` handler, only do it if `isLoading` is false).

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I've been checking with `if (myLabel == null) {give it a value}` which still resulted in an error. But checking if not equal is the way to go. Would it be possible to use the same method of binding to bind a `CornerRadius` to a `Border`? I haven't seen a BorderRadius property that works in this manner.

Comment: Yep, should be possible. See [CornerRadius](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.cornerradius.aspx) and [CornerRadiusProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.cornerradiusproperty.aspx). If it doesn't work as-is, you might need to write an `IValueConverter` to use as a `Converter` that takes a `double` and returns a `CornerRadius`.